# Signature XML verification failed C#

Tags: c#, xml, signature, banking

I need to implements EBICS protocol and sign the HPB XML request.

My signature is correctly generated in my XML file but when the server verify it, i get the following return and I don't understand why :

> Authentication Signature Invalid

Can you help me to solve my problem ?

This is my code to generate my signature :

**Method : SignXml()**

```
public static void SignXml()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDoc.Load("hpbtest.xml");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        X509Certificate2 Cert = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        Key.FromXmlString(Cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
        // Create a SignedXml object.
        PrefixedSignedXML signedXml = new PrefixedSignedXML(xmlDoc);
        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])";
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
        env.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature("ds");
        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml("ds");
        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        xmlDoc.Save("hpbtest.xml");
    }
```

**Class PrefixedSignedXml**

```
public class PrefixedSignedXML : SignedXml
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocumentToSign;
    public PrefixedSignedXML(XmlDocument document)
        : base(document)
    {
        xmlDocumentToSign = document;
    }

    public PrefixedSignedXML(XmlElement element)
        : base(element)
    { }

    public PrefixedSignedXML()
        : base()
    { }

    public void ComputeSignature(string prefix)
    {
        this.BuildDigestedReferences();
        AsymmetricAlgorithm signingKey = this.SigningKey;
        if (signingKey == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_LoadKeyFailed");
        }
        SignatureDescription description = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod)as SignatureDescription;
        if (description == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_SignatureDescriptionNotCreated");
        }
        HashAlgorithm hash = description.CreateDigest();
        if (hash == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_CreateHashAlgorithmFailed");
        }
        this.GetC14NDigest(hash, prefix);
        this.m_signature.SignatureValue = description.CreateFormatter(signingKey).CreateSignature(hash);
    }

    public XmlElement GetXml(string prefix)
    {
        XmlElement e = this.GetXml();
        SetPrefix(prefix, e);
        return e;
    }

    private void BuildDigestedReferences()
    {
        Type t = typeof(SignedXml);
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("BuildDigestedReferences", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        m.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
    }

    private byte[] GetC14NDigest(HashAlgorithm hash, string prefix)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.PreserveWhitespace = false;//Aucune influence sur la signature
        XmlElement e = this.SignedInfo.GetXml();
        document.AppendChild(document.ImportNode(e, true));
        Transform canonicalizationMethodObject = this.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject;
        SetPrefix(prefix, document.DocumentElement); 
        canonicalizationMethodObject.LoadInput(document);
        return canonicalizationMethodObject.GetDigestedOutput(hash);
    }

    private void SetPrefix(String prefix, XmlNode node)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
            SetPrefix(prefix, n);
        node.Prefix = prefix;
    }

    public override XmlElement GetIdElement(XmlDocument document, string idValue)
    {
        XmlElement matchingElement = null;
        try
        {
            matchingElement = base.GetIdElement(document, idValue);
        }
        catch (Exception idElementException)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(idElementException.ToString());
        }

        if (matchingElement == null)
        {
            // at this point, idValue = xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])
            string customXPath = idValue.TrimEnd(')');
            customXPath = customXPath.Substring(customXPath.IndexOf('(') + 1);
            matchingElement = xmlDocumentToSign.SelectSingleNode(customXPath) as XmlElement;
        }
        return matchingElement;
    }
}
```

**Class RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription**

```
public class RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription),"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    }
    public RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription()
    {
        KeyAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider";
        DigestAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed";
        FormatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter";
        DeformatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter";
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureDeformatter = (AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(DeformatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureDeformatter;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureFormatter =
            (AsymmetricSignatureFormatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(FormatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureFormatter;
    }
}
```

**Final signature result**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebics.org/H003" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebics.org/H003 http://www.ebics.org/H003/ebics_keymgmt_request.xsd" Version="H003" Revision="1">
  <header authenticate="true">
    <static>
      <HostID>EBIXQUAL</HostID>
      <Nonce>234AB2340FD2C23035764578FF3092D3</Nonce>
      <Timestamp>2015-12-04T10:07:27.123Z</Timestamp>
      <PartnerID>AD598</PartnerID>
      <UserID>EF056</UserID>
      <OrderDetails>
        <OrderType>HPB</OrderType>
        <OrderAttribute>DZHNN</OrderAttribute>
      </OrderDetails>
      <SecurityMedium>0000</SecurityMedium>
    </static>
    <mutable />
  </header>
  <AuthSignature>
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <ds:Reference URI="#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <ds:DigestValue>2glaCqpZf0XMkqB+twtAsJtKo9MWg60FaMBwJ91xNGQ=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>FISRuQ0WTanCkvhc9/m/9OIHCd+hfPl4WjqVlhPQx5AoBe/yNFBQoXwC+d3os7kaxDvZghIosLzcIc/69M5YUAn/njlWAzYL+pqtXXy3Ea9SxMqeb3BwPVLMfkgY2TUo7QIlnv+omUPRq0PzDi50iZFv4sh+TBdWIEs29JJET/48MP+d67MqpdN5NRtM3C2QDWpRhe4erKoRCJC1OW+DkIHdKZ4lqJpKp1cdcooCRGXod9+6usxbfD8LU0Ow7wTJl2crUya9Elx+gxGUogo7bBrRnRpWM/5ih12KcoXQ/mKRpwKCbk+vYRF9E66/2SVjRZSkmFm1xeENRiZJ5tJDRg==</ds:SignatureValue>
  </AuthSignature>
  <body />
</ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest>
```

I'm really try everything and I don't understand why it not work :(

Thank you in advance !

Thomas

Comment: How and where is the signature verified? Why you have to customize so many elements rather than sticking with simple approach?

Comment: The signature is verified by the bank server. 
I need to customize these elements because Ebics accept only this XML Structure.